# Wikipedia API - get full information from infobox

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

i am trying to extract the parent company information (in infobox pane) for a page such as "KFC".

If you access the

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KFC

url... the info box contains the property (Parent = Yum! Brands)

.. howver, when i access through the PHP API.. the parent info is not included.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=KFC&rvsection=0

How do i ensure that Wikipedia API returns the "Parent = " information as well (for a brand term like "KFC"). Essentially, I want to extract info that Yum Brands is the parent of KFC through the wikipedia API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [wikipedia wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#APIs_for_bots) official ways of getting informations.

My suggestion would be to use the screen scraping throught [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which will always be the best, even if it's deprecated. The only downside is that if Wikipedia changes how it looks like you will have to update your code.

A  [guide](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)  to PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Edit:

At least i'm doing something instead of linking to non working resources and downvoting right answers ...

Here's the code I made to get the Parent company information from the Infobox pane with the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

```
<?php

//The folder where you uploaded simple_html_dom.php
require_once('/homepages/../htdocs/simple_html_dom.php');

//Wikipedia page to parse
$html = file_get_html('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KFC');


foreach ( $html->find ( 'tr th a[title=Holding company]' ) as $element ) {
    $element = $element->parent;
    $element = $element->parent;

    $tabella = $element->find ( 'td', 0 );

    //Now $parent contains "Yum! Brands"
    $parent = $tabella->plaintext;

    echo $parent;

}

?>
```

If this answer suit your needs please choose it as best answer and upvote it because it took me a lot of effort, about 1 hour =/

Thanks ;)

Comment: ChicagoDude is already using the MediaWiki API - suggesting that he read Wikipedia's documentation directing him to use this API is not useful, let alone a solution.

Comment: I'm directing him to use a DOM Parser, which seems the only solution